# Custom components not being matched using react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to separate concerns with my Routes, keep my react code more organized. I am currently using **`react-router-dom`** v5.

I have an `Application Routes` component that has 3 children as components

- `AuthenticatedRoutes`
- `PublicRoutes`
- `Error404Route`

Each component renders different routes/components, but only the first component (`AuthenticatedRoutes`) is being matched.

**Application Routes**

```
export const ApplicationRoutes = () => (
  <Switch>
    <AuthenticatedRoutes />
    <PublicRoutes />
    <Error404Route />
  </Switch>
);
```

**Authenticated Routes**

```
export const AuthenticatedRoutes = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/dashboard'>
      <Dashboard />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path='/profile'>
      <Profile />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
);
```

**Public Routes**

```
export const PublicRoutes = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/about'>
      <About />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path='/'>
      <Home />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
);
```

**Error Route**

```
export const Error404Route = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route>
      <Error404 />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
);
```

So, was I was saying only the `AuthenticatedRoutes` (`/dashboard` and `/profile`) are being matched, the **public routes** and **error404** route are not.

I thought that if you used a Switch the route will try to match the location pathname, if not, then the Error404Route will display.

Am I missing something? (sure I am)

Thanks!

Comment: whats the point of having so many switches? I think removing all your inner switches would fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

**Application Routes**

```
import AuthenticatedRoutes from './AuthenticatedRoutes'
import PublicRoutes from './PublicRoutes'
import Error404Route from './Error404Route'

export const ApplicationRoutes = () => (
  <Switch>
    {AuthenticatedRoutes}
    {PublicRoutes}
    {Error404Route}
  </Switch>
);
```

**Authenticated Routes**

```
import Dashboard from './Dashboard'
import Profile from './Profile'

export const AuthenticatedRoutes = [
  <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard}/>,
  <Route exact path='/profile' component={Profile}>,
];
```

**Public Routes**

```
import Home from './Home'
import About from './About'

export const PublicRoutes = [
  <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>,
  <Route exact path='/about' component={About}>,
];
```

**Error Routes**

```
import Error404 from './Error404'

export const Error404Route = [
  <Route exact path='/' component={Error404}/>,
];
```